Quotient of a ring by a left ideal
This is a simple algebra question I'm struggling with.

Let $A$ be a ring (with unity) and $I\subset A$ a left ideal and $B\subset A$ a two sided Ideal.
$A/I=B$ and $A/B=I$ (in the category of left $A$-modules)
Suppose that we have two short exact sequences (category of left $A$-modules) $$I\to_{i} A\to_{f} B$$ and
$$B\to_{j} A\to_{r} I$$ with $i$ and $j$ are the obvious embeddings $r\circ i=id_{I}$ and $f\circ j=id_{B}$. Also $r$ and $f$ are maps of left $A$-modules.

My question is very naive: Does it follow that $B$ is also a ring with unity or equivalently does it follow that $I\subset A$ is a two sided ideal ?

No. Let $F$ be a field, $A = \{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}: a, b, c \in F\}$, $I = \{\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}: a \in F\}$, and $B = \{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}: b, c \in F\}$.
